# Stack overflow when manipulating Bi-dimensional integer array

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I wrote this C++ program to sort an integer matrix using selection sort. I tried to compile and run the program. But I ran into a stack overflow error and the message also said something about an access violation writing location .

I tried the following steps:

1. Tried reducing the array size from 50 x 50 to 10 x 10.
2. Tried heap allocation to the resultant array (using new).
3. Tried declaring the resultant array as static.
4. Tried examining the Memory option in Debug Menu for that particular memory 
   location(but couldn't make sense of it).
5. Tried examining the chkstk.asm file that the IDE automatically opened.

But all these efforts were of no use.

This is the part of the source code involved in the runtime error.

```
void SelectionSort(int matrix[][10], int rowMax, int colMax)
{
    //Runtime error was pointed over here.

    int smallest, temp, position, count = 0;
    int resultant[10][10];

    for (int row = 0; row < rowMax; row++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rowMax - 1; j++)
        {
            smallest = matrix[row][j];
            position = j;

            for (int k = j + 1; k < rowMax; k++)
            {
                if (matrix[row][k] < smallest)
                {
                    smallest = matrix[row][k];
                    position = k;
                }
            }
            temp = matrix[row][j];
            matrix[row][j] = matrix[row][position];
            matrix[row][position] = temp;
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rowMax; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < colMax; j++)
            resultant[i][j] = matrix[j][i];

    if (count == 0)
    {
        SelectionSort(resultant, rowMax, colMax);
        count++;
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "The sorted matrix is: " << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowMax; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < colMax; j++)
            {
                std::cout << matrix[i][j] << "  ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
                }
        }
}
```

These were the messages that were thrown.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF79D763488 in Sorting Algorithm Benchmarking Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000BFBF600000. occurred
```

and

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF79D763488 in Sorting Algorithm Benchmarking Program.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000058CE0B3000). occurred
```

I expected the sorted matrix to be printed in the console.

For example, if the unsorted matrix is:
1   9   5
8   3   6
7   4   2

then the output should be:
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9

I would request you not to send complicated template-based suggestions, as I am in the intermediate level of C++ programming.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `count` is initialized to 0 and not changed before `if (count == 0)`, so that test will always be true. The code will call `SelectionSort` from inside `SelectionSort`, ad infinitum, or until stack overflow. Selection sort doesn't need to be recursive; just write a loop that repeats until no exchanges have been made.

Comment: Could you please suggest a better alternative? (I wanted to sort the matrix row-wise first, transpose it and to sort it row-wise again.)

Comment: Oh, I see: 'resultant` is the **transpose**. Regardless, a loop is almost always better than recursion. So you want to make two passes, sorting the array, transposing it, and sorting the transpose? `for (int count = 0; ; ++count) { /* sort the array */ if (count == 1) break; /* transpose the array */ }`

Comment: If you sure you logic is good with recursion, you may try to change variable `count` declaration to add `static` - that way it will be same for all recursions and  move `count++;` to before call of recursion.

Comment: Your current approach takes time. So from the input 2d array, you can change it into a new 1d array then sort the latter with the method you want and finally output the result.

Comment: @HelloEveryone That's OK. I wanted an approach that was easy to follow as per the algorithm.

Comment: @HelloEveryone Plus I'll be measuring the time it takes to sort.